# how to decrease queries in php/mysql array selection loop

Tags: php, mysql

i need to show stories details and tags' names in my php/mysql project .

for every story row,  there is a filed named : tags that save tags id as an array

> Table name: **stories**
>
> table filed : **tags**

example of tags filed :

> **1 5 6**
>   space between them

and i have a tag table that looks like this

> Table name : **bt_tags**
>
> Table fileds : **tid,tag**

now problem :

when using while loop to fetch all fields in story table , the page uses 1 query to show every stories' detail  but for showing tag's names  , i should query another table to find names , we have ids stored in story table

now i used for loop between while loop  to show tag names  but im sure there is a better way to decrease page queries

llowed to change anything in database table

**how can i improve this script and show tag's names without using  **for loop**  ?**

Comment: If you're not allowed to change the database tables, I'm not sure how much we can really do here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT stories.storyid,
       stories.storyname, 
       group_concat( tags.tagname ) 
  FROM stories, tags
 WHERE CONCAT( ' ', stories.tags, ' ' ) LIKE CONCAT( '%', tags.tagid, '%' ) 
 GROUP BY stories.storyid, stories.storyname
```

Comment: nice one but i was not successful to make it work , 
how can i show the array of tag names after query that

Comment: Change `group_concat( tags.tagname ) ` to `group_concat( tags.tagname )  as mytags`, replacing `mytags` with whatever you want, and you should be able to reference it like `$row['mytags']`

Answer (score 4):

Sounds like a join may help you

```
select s.*,
  b.tag,
  b.slug
from story_table s
  left join bt_tags b on b.tid in s.tags
```

[Join Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/join.html) at dev.mysql.com

Comment: this seams to be great bro! ;-)

Comment: I dont know why i cant set this to work , actually , tag ids stored in stories table seprated by space not comma

Comment: and how to show array of tag names ? just $row['tag'] ? 
plz help to complete this script

Comment: The example query is in short hand; you'll need to swap out somethings.  In place of `s.tags` you could probably use your `$tags_id` variable

Comment: would you mind updating your answer , i think with example , i can understand it better .

Comment: "tag ids stored in stories table seprated by space not comma"  

Makes this very difficult.  If you have a to-many relationship which you seem to have you should probably be using a cross reference table of sorts instead.  

If you can, convert your spaces to commas in this field.  

Using `$tags_id` is also not an option as I suggested; it's made after you run the first query, which is counter to what you're trying to do.

Comment: I can't tell without running it but you should try @mark-baker's solution

Comment: the only problem to your code is that it fetches only first tag name and not the rest